# Java : Static Methods and Static Blocks Output

Tags: java

This is the source code for demonstrating a static block and static method.

```
class StaticDemo
{
static int count=10;

 StaticDemo(){
 count++;
 }
 static void display(){
  System.out.println(count);
 }

 static{
  System.out.println("Static Block written Before Main");
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
     StaticDemo t1=new StaticDemo();
     StaticDemo t2=new StaticDemo();

     StaticDemo.display();
     t2.display();

  }
  static{
     System.out.println("Static Block written After Main");
  }
 }
```

I expect an output of

```
Static Block written Before Main 
Static Block written After Main 
11
12
```

whereas I get an output of

```
Static Block written Before Main 
Static Block written After Main 
12
12
```

I understand that the static blocks are the first set of code to be executed and hence the order of the first 2 statements. However, when the JVM creates the object t1 of StaticDemo class, doesn't the value of count get incremented to 11 ( 10+1 )? When does the initialization/increment actually occur in the program? 
Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect? It works just as should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
             //Initially value of count is 10
             StaticDemo t1=new StaticDemo(); //here it becomes 11
             StaticDemo t2=new StaticDemo(); //here it becomes 12

             StaticDemo.display(); //Now you are printing, it will print 12
             t2.display(); //The value has not changed, so again 12

          }
```

If you re-write the block as:

```
 public static void main(String args[]){

             StaticDemo t1=new StaticDemo(); 
             StaticDemo.display(); 
             StaticDemo t2=new StaticDemo(); 
              t2.display(); 

          }
```

Then you should see the output as 11, 12

Answer (score 4):

The increment occurs in the constructor.  You call the constructor twice before displaying the counter so it is incremented twice.  If you place the display() between the two constructor calls you will see `11 12` as you expect.

BTW You can see all this by stepping through the code in your debugger.

Answer (score 3):

The output is explained by the order of the statements in your `main` method:

```
 StaticDemo t1=new StaticDemo();       //this increments count to 11
 StaticDemo t2=new StaticDemo();       //this increments count to 12

 StaticDemo.display();                 //this outputs 12
 t2.display();                         //this outputs 12
```

Essentially, you're incrementing twice, then outputting twice - hence the result.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your constructor -

```
StaticDemo(){
    count++;
}
```

You are incrementing the static variable every time you create an object. You've created two objects here, so it will get incremented by two. This explains why you are getting 12 two times.

To get your "expected" output -

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    StaticDemo t1=new StaticDemo();    // count got incremented, now contains 11
    StaticDemo.display();    // will print 11

    StaticDemo t2=new StaticDemo();  // again count got incremented
    t2.display();    // will print 12
}
```

I hope this clears up the actual output for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
     StaticDemo t1=new StaticDemo();
     StaticDemo.display();
     StaticDemo t2=new StaticDemo();
     t2.display();

  }
```

Output:

Static Block written Before Main
Static Block written After Main
11
12

edit://
problem is you call display(), after you called the constructer 2 times. because display() using the same value you get each time 12

**edit2:// to late sry**

Answer (score 0):

@user2315188..

Your are creating t1 and t2 objects so the no-argument constructor call 2 times,the first time count values is 11 and second time the count become 12 so you are getting output 12,12

```
     StaticDemo t1=new StaticDemo();
     StaticDemo t2=new StaticDemo();
```